# Error al hacer un array bidimensional index out of bound java

Tags: java

estaba haciendo un ejercicio el cual tengo que hacer dos matrices de tamaño
3x3, sumarlas y mostrar su suma. Estaba intentando pintar la matriz 1, en este caso llamada t1
la cual en teoria es 3x3 y está rellena todo de 2.

Cuando la muestro por pantalla con el código de abajo, me da un error diciendo

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
at ejercicios3pdf.P03_ejercicio.main(P03_ejercicio.java:17)**

Lo cual no entiendo porque el index 2 se sale, no entiendo el error del código

```
   package ejercicios3pdf;
    
    public class P03_ejercicio {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            int [][] t1 = {{2,2,2},{2,2,2}};
            int [][] t2 = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1}};
            int [][] t3 = new int [3][3];
            
        
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    System.out.print(t1[i][j]);
                }
            }
            
    
            
        
        
        }
    
    }
```

Pero si cambio en el for de la i que sea menor que 2, no me da el error

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(t1[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Y luego con esta array bidimensional 2x2 saca de google no me da error y en los for, los 2, la i y la j son mientras que sean menor a 2

```
    int[][] arr = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
      
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
```

¿Alguien me explica el por qué? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta: estaba haciendo 2x2 osea, tenía que rellenar manualmente otro más si quería que fuera de 3x3:

{{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{2,2,2}};

Answer (score 0):

Para formar un arreglo de 2 dimensiones, se crea con Renglones y columnas.

En tu ejemplo tienes

```
int [][] t1 = {
                 {2,2,2}, // Renglon 1
                 {2,2,2}  // Renglon 2
               };
```

Es por eso que cuando cambias los index de los for a 2, funciona, si pones el primer ciclo en 2 y el segundo en 3 te debe de funcionar.

Saludos
Israel Ramos